# Proof of power series

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, power-series

I just started studying power series and I got stuck at this proving the following.

> Let $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ converge in $(-R,R)$ for $R>0$
>
> If $f(x)=0$ $\forall x\in(-R,R)$, prove $a_n=0$ $\forall n$

I really don't know what to do, since $f(x)$ converge, should I use Cauchy condition? If $f(x)$ converge in $(-R,R)$, is it centered around $a=0$?

Comment: hint: In $(-R,R)$, not only $\sum a_nx^n$ converges, but also $\sum a_nx^n$ absolutely converges. (i.e., $\sum |a_nx^n|$ converges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\sum a_nx^n$ converges absolutely on $(-R,R)$ too, that is, $\sum |a_nx^n|$ converges for all $x\in(-R,R)$. Let's take a look at the point other than $0$. To help you understand, let's suppose $3\in (-R,R)$, and we look at $3$. (Just to ease the symbols. )

Since $\sum |a_n3^n|$ converges, the partial sum $s_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n |a_n\cdot 3^n|$ also converges. And also notice this partial sum $\langle s_n\rangle $ is an increasing sequence whose limit is $0$ (the hypothesis). If there exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $a_N\neq 0$, then since $s_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n |a_n\cdot 3^n|$ is made up of a lot of nonnegative terms, then $s_N>0$. By the Monotone Sequence Theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\sup \langle s_n\rangle$, and we know that $\sup\langle s_n\rangle\geq s_N>0$ (greatest lower bound $\geq$ every term), so $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n>0$, it contradicts to our settings.

So for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $a_n=0$.

PS: I suggest you memorize this frequently used little fact: If $\sum a_n$ is a series of nonnegative terms (I mean $a_i\ge 0$ for all $i\in\Bbb N$), then its partial sum $\langle s_n\rangle$ is an increasing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** What happens if a particular $a_n \neq 0$?

Comment: If only a particular $a_k\neq 0$ and all the others $a_n=0$ I should see that $a_kx^k=0$, right? However $x$ can be $0$, so there is no need for $a_k=0$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (-R,R)$, not just $x=0$, right?